# Не подключается скрипт js в html

Tags: javascript, html

Не могу понять почему когда скрипт внутри html файла - он работает , а когда я выношу скрипт в отдельный файл и кидают ссылку на него в тег  - он перестает работать . Хелп ми плиз.

```
<body>
<h1>RPG admin panel</h1>
<h2>Account list</h2>
<table id="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Race</th>
        <th>Profession</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Birthday</th>
        <th>Banned</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
    </tbody>
</table>
<script src="../js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Js:

```
    let url = "/rest/players";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(url,
        function (json) {
            let tr;
            for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].id + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].name + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].title + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].race + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].profession + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].level + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].birthday + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + json[i].banned + "</td>");
                $('#tableBody').append(tr);
            }
        });
});
```

Фото директории проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В атрибут `type` пишите тип скрипта (пример: `text/javascrpt`), источник скрипта нужно записывать через `src` - `src="../js/script.js"`

Comment: К сожалению это не исправило ситуации (

Comment: А  вы точно указали корректную папку?

Comment: Попробуйте либо так: `src="/js/script.js"`, либо так: `src="./js/script.js"`.

Comment: Сейчас прикреплю скрин с директорией

Comment: @NNL993 не помогло (

Comment: Mожет `src="../../js/script.js"`? Даже уже не уверен что поможет...

Comment: попробуйте кэш почистить или запустить в браузере, где ещё не открывали

Comment: К сожалению и этот путь не подходит . Мой - корректный идейка подскзывает.

Comment: @Danila открыл через другой браузер - ничего не изменилось . Оно как будто не видит файл со скриптом

Comment: В консоли 0 ошибок?

Comment: перезагрузил - появилась такая ошибка в консоле браузера  GET http://localhost:8080/js/script.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: значит, всё-таки неправильный путь: у Вас же папка js не в корне сайта лежит, а ссылка формируется такая, будто папка в корневом каталоге

Comment: Покажите путь к скрипту от корня сайта и покажите путь к странице, где вы подключаете скрипт тоже от корня сайта.

Comment: Путь просто js/script.js

Comment: Можете попробовать html файл перенести из папки "html" в папку webapp